# Pi4+ runs Elasticsearch cluster of 1, gives yellow status

Tags: elasticsearch, raspbian

I am currently running Elasticsearch 7.3.2 on a Rasbian (Buster) instance on a Raspberry Pi 4+.  It looks like it was running in a green status for a few days, processing files, but suddenly, i noticed a Yellow Status. I looked into gc.log and the file was showing that there is a

```
Entering Safepoint region: GenCollectForAllocation
Pause Young (Allocation Failure)
Using 4 workers of 4 for Evaluation
Desired survivor size 3342336 bytes, new threshold 6 (max threshold 6)
```

I am trying to get this back to green, but i am not sure if this is going to be a major issue or not.  It does look like it will leave a safepoint region, and then within a fraction of a second will hit it again.

When looking at my mounted NAS, i noticed that it is only 34% full, but im not sure the best approach to solve this

When I ping elasticsearch with: `curl localhost:9200/_cat/nodes?pretty` it returns:

```
{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [{
      "type": "circuit_breaking_exception",
      "reason": "[parent] Data too large, data for [<http request>] would be [1059250992/1010.1mb], which is larger than the limit of [1013704294/966.7mb], real usage: [1059250992/1010.1mb], new bytes reserved: [0/0b], usages [request=0/0b, fielddata=0/0b, in_flight_requests=0/0b, accounting=818200108/780.2mb]",
      "bytes_wanted": 1059250992,
      "bytes_limit":  1010704294,
      "durability": "PERMANENT"
    }],
    ...
    "status": 429
  }
}
```

Is this something I can easily resolve in the Elasticsearch yml file in terms of limitations?

Answer (score 0):

Yellow usually means you have all your primary shards, but some replica shards are un-allocated. On a cluster with a single node, I wouldn't expect you to have replica shards. I would recommend looking at [_cat/shards](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/cat-shards.html) to make sure you only have primary shards and no replicas (it's in column 3; `p` or `r`).

Comment: I see 2 entries.  a p, STARTED and a  r UNASSIGNED.  The unassigned though has no additional information.

Comment: Not sure why there is an unassigned replica shard though.

Comment: You can just get rid of it by telling Elasticsearch you want 0 replicas on that index. [docs here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-update-settings.html)

Comment: I see it in the docs you linked as the expample, but there are no entries for the key: "number_of_replicas" do you have something better as proof?  Right now im running a vanilla yaml file that i can change which has no references to additional nodes.  I can show you the file if you like as proof, but im trying to figure out not only how to resolve this, but prevent it from cropping up again later.

Comment: different indices can have different replication configurations, so it is not a cluster-wide setting, and therefore does not reside in the YAML. If you are trying to prevent it from happening again I would recommend looking at how that index was created. There is a `index.number_of_replicas` option, but this is only the default value for new indices, and can be overridden when creating an index.